# Calculating statistics for each polygon in multipolygon feature separately

Tags: google-earth-engine-javascript-api

I have 10 sample points of  region of interest. I perform 30 meter buffer around each point. Now i need to calculate mean of pixels that fall in each polygon separately . When i perform reduceRegion in GEE, it returns 1 mean for all polygons in each band not  12 independent values for mean.

How can i calculate mean of pixels in each buffer polygon separately?

https://code.earthengine.google.com/2609c8804f14c9ace9815ec99dd0f50d

```
var roi_buf=p.buffer(100)
var f_L9 = L9.filterBounds(roi_buf)
             .filterDate('2023-07-01','2023-9-30')
             .filter(ee.Filter.lt('CLOUD_COVER',2))
             .filter(ee.Filter.contains('.geo',region));

print(f_L9)
var scale_factor=function(image){
  var opt_b =image.select('SR_B.').multiply(0.0000275).add(-0.2);
  var thr_b =image.select('ST_B.*').multiply(0.00341802).add(149.0);
  return image.addBands(opt_b,null,true).addBands(thr_b,null,true)
};

var L9_img=ee.Image('LANDSAT/LC09/C02/T1_L2/LC09_168034_20230815');
L9_img=scale_factor(L9_img);

var mean_dict=L9_img.select(['SR_B2','SR_B3','SR_B4']).reduceRegion({
  reducer:ee.Reducer.mean(),
  geometry : roi_buf,
  scale:30
});
print(mean_dict)
print(roi_buf.geometries())
//Map.addLayer(L9_img.clip(region),RGB_vis,'RGB')
Map.centerObject(region,10)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, you're calculating statistics across all the buffered points at once because they're part of a single geometry. To fix this, you'll need to treat each point as a separate feature.

### Step 1

Convert your points from a single `MultiPoint` geometry to a `FeatureCollection` of points. You can do that through the drawing interface.

Click the gear icon next to your geometry:

[image]

Change `Import as` to `FeatureCollection`.
[image]

### Step 2

Now instead of buffering the `MultiPoint`, you need to buffer each point separately using a `map`:

```js
var roi_buf = p.map(function(pt) {return pt.buffer(100)})
```

You'll also get an error when you try to print `roi_buf.geometries()`, so you can remove that line or change it to `roi_buf.geometry()`.

### Step 3

Finally, use `reduceRegions` instead of `reduceRegion` to calculate statistics over each buffered point:

```js
var mean_dict=L9_img.select(['SR_B2','SR_B3','SR_B4']).reduceRegions({
  reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
  collection: roi_buf,
  scale: 30
});
```

The output will be a `FeatureCollection` where each `Feature` contains the reflectance over that buffered point.

Comment: Thank you very much. It works.